# add Background to surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview, 2d-games

I have been trying to follow this tutorial, https://o7planning.org/en/10521/android-2d-game-tutorial-for-beginners#, and that worked well! 
I just really want to add an background image to it... and that does not work so well. 
I have made a png image i really want to use as an background.

When i try to use `setBackground()` in the SurfaceView, the whole game just freezes. 
how do i set the background properly?

Comment: Why not use another view and set the background to that view?

Comment: i set the background view as ```setContentView(new GameSurface(this))```
when i try to set it to another view, and implement Gamesurface into that view i just get a heck load of errors hahahah